# How to return large data structures efficiently.

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

Say I have a vector of objects

```
std::vector<int> data;
```

This vector will be very large (megabytes in size). I have a function that needs to return this data structure. If I return this data structure "by-value" will a copy of the vector be made?

```
std::vector<int> generate()
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    //Populate data
    return data;
}
```

How efficient would this operation be compared to allocating the vector on the heap and passing a pointer to the vector?

```
std::vector<int>* generate()
{
    std::vector<int>* data = new std::vector<int>();
    //Populate data
    return data; 
}
```

Comment: Passing back the pointer has the hidden cost of needing to manually memory management. Thus you need to factor in all the code you add to track that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern compilers know how to optimize this into a simple *move*. Your first example is sufficiently efficient; you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Even old compilers know how to optimize this away (RVO and NRVO) allow  elision of the copy.

Answer (score 5):

In your particular case, most compilers will perform NRVO - Named Return Value Optimization. This means no data will be copied, but it is not guaranteed. There are cases when NRVO will not be used. In C++11 and up vector might still use move semantics which will be very efficent.

[edit]

To clarify, if you use C++11 compatible compiler then your code is efficient, if you are stuck with C++03 then to be safe better return in function parameter (by reference), as in some contexts you might end with copying.

Comment: And C++17 _guarantees_ copy-elision.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an empty `std::vector` initially and then return by reference as follows if your code structure permits:

```
std::vector<int>& generate(std::vector<int>& _vec) {
    // populate _vec
    return _vec;
}
```

This saves from having to use pointers or create copies.

Comment: This was "okay" practice 10 years ago; it is outdated and has no place in modern code.

Comment: @ildjarn Sure, might not be the best solution but it is a solution nonetheless. Take it or leave it.

Comment: If it isn't an _improvement_ then it isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use c++11 vector could be moved and it is very cheap, just few words exchanged